# Changing default theme in Jhipster project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jhipster, bootswatch

Hi I am new to **jhipster**. I could get the default project working fine and it is very good. 
What I want to change is the default bootstrap theme.
I have already tried

`bower install flat-admin-bootstrap-templates --save`

but somehow it does not change anything.

I tried **bootswatch** as well, but I am not sure how to keep one theme always selected by default. I am sure i can do this by changing code. But i am sure there is another easier way.

Could someone throw some light. How do i change the default theme?

Answer (score 2):

As of JHipster 6, Bootswatch theme selection is included in questions when generating a new project: 'Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)?'

For older versions, try one of the themes available in [JHipster's module market](https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/list).

You can also read this [tip about bootswatch](https://jhipster.github.io/tips/009_tips_using_bootswatch_themes.html) which is no longer valid for JHipster 3.x but give you an idea of the steps that are executed by the modules above.

Comment: The market place does not have the required theme. If i have a different theme like flat-admin-bootstrap-templates, do i have to make it Jhipster module? Sounds like too much work.

Comment: The only benefit to make a module is when you want to apply same theme to several projects otherwise you just make your manual changes. Code generated by JHipster is yours, you do what you want with it. Also flat-admin-bootstrap-templates is more than a theme, it's a theme with templates which will require more work to integrate in any existing app.

Comment: Thanks. Yes looks to me like a complicated task. 
I am trying to understand http://www.jhipster-book.com/#!/news/entry/integrating-angulr-into-jhipster.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Deleted the comment and will add it in SO for future reference. Thank You

Comment: As of JHipster 6, Bootswatch theme selection is included in questions when generating a new porject: 'Would you like to use a Bootswatch theme (https://bootswatch.com/)?'

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it by replacing content of `_variable.scss` in `\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss` by the `_variable.scss` provided by [bootswatch for bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606101124/http://bootswatch.com/4-alpha/)